# How do I handle special characters?

Tags: display-suite

I use the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module and I enabled the Display Suite Format module. I use a code field to display a node/edit link, with the following code:

```
  if (node_access('update', $entity)) {
    print l(t('Modifier'), 'node/' . $entity->nid . '/edit?nid=' . [node:field-construction-fdr-ref:nid]);
  }
?>
```

The resulting URL is `http://localhost/node/11430/edit%3Fnid%3D11419`, leading to a *Page not found* error. I wish to get `http://localhost/node/11430/edit?nid=11419`.

I tried */* before *?* and *=*; I tried *&_#63;* for *?* and *&_#61;* for *=*.

How can I get the URL I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query params should be passed to the function in a keyed array:

```
$query = array(
  'nid' => 123,
  'foo' => 'bar',
);
$params = array('query' => $query);

print l(t('Modifier'), 'node/' . $entity->nid . '/edit', $params);
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works.

here is my code :

`<?php
  if (node_access('update', $entity)) {
$query = array(
  'nid' => [node:field-construction-fdr-ref:nid],
);
$params = array('query' => $query);
    print l(t('Modifier'), 'node/' . $entity->nid . '/edit' , $params );
  }
?>`